# I just installed sublime text 3 on my laptop. I cant run C codes

Tags: sublime-text-3, gcc, mingw

I built some build systems by using various codes from google & youtube but cant make it. every time some error is showing. is there any way of solving this? Last time i used this code to build a system

**{
 "shell_cmd" : "gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name}",
 "working_dir" : "$file_path",
 "variants":
  [
   {
     "name": "Run",
     "shell_cmd": "gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name} &&  ${file_path}/${file_base_name}"
   }
  ]
}**strong text****

but errors are showing like

gcc: error: Take: No such file or directory
gcc: error: five: No such file or directory
gcc: error: numbers: No such file or directory
gcc: error: using: No such file or directory
gcc: error: array: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Unable to initialize device PRN
Unable to initialize device PRN
[Finished in 0.2s]

My code was

## include

int main()
{
    int i, exr[5];

```
for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
{
scanf("%d", &exr[i]);
}
for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
{
    printf("exr[%d]=%d\n",i, exr[i]);
}
```

}

[sample code to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF1H2.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text is only a text editor. It is not a compiler.

The configuration you are using requires GCC to be installed. GCC is not a component of Sublime Text; it must be installed separately.

Comment: yeah i installed mingw file separately but its not working. ive gcc compiler attached to codeblocks. will that be a problem? btw thanks for you answer.